# UFW rule to allow LAN traffic

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I have UFW setup and enough rules to allow me to be able to do what I need to do on a regular basis except for one thing. To be able to access anything on my LAN (NAS, printer, Chromecasts, etc.) I have to turn the firewall off briefly since I can't figure out what has to be open to be able to access those things.

Is there a way to make a rule to allow access to everything on my LAN? If not, would it be safe to allow access in and out to the IP address of my NAS, printer, etc.? I have everything setup to have static IP's so this is really easy for me to do as long as it would be safe. I have been using Ubuntu for a few years but I am just starting to dive into UFW a little more as well as networking in general. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5):

You can allow your LAN range

```
sudo ufw allow to 192.168.1.0/24
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

The network portion of your IP may be different (probably a 1 on the third octet). Check with `ip addr`.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/a/74024)

Comment: You could use "192.168.0.0/16" for the whole private network range. https://www.arin.net/reference/research/statistics/address_filters/

Comment: although they say:  In some cases, Regional Internet Registries (RIRs) have issued adjacent address space to their customers and that space is in use on the global Internet.